# How to calculate a true-MACD for a single point in MQL4?

Tags: algorithm, calculus, mql4, mt4

I know you can utilize the built in **`iMACD()`** function but it uses a variant of what I need. I am only interested in the first point. When accessing **`MACDLineBuffer[1]`** I get the correct value. However **`SignalLineBuffer[1]`** and consequently **`HistogramBuffer[1]`** are significantly off.

```
int SignalMAPeriod = 9;
double alpha   = 2.0 / (SignalMAPeriod + 1.0);
double alpha_1 = 1.0 - alpha;

   for(int i=limit; i>=0; i--)
   {
      MACDLineBuffer[i]   = iMA(NULL,0,FastMAPeriod,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i)
                          - iMA(NULL,0,SlowMAPeriod,0,MODE_EMA,PRICE_CLOSE,i);

      SignalLineBuffer[i] = alpha   * MACDLineBuffer[i]
                          + alpha_1 * SignalLineBuffer[i+1];

      HistogramBuffer[i]  = MACDLineBuffer[i]
                          - SignalLineBuffer[i];
   }
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: How to get the true MACD from a single point.

Comment: Do you need signal line from a regular macd? it uses simple averaging of the difference. if you need an expotential averaging - look at the standard macd code and replace `SimpleMaOnBuffer()` with `ExponentialMaOnBuffer()`